# How does $\frac{x^2 + 6x + 5}{x^2 - x - 2}$ simplify to $\frac{(x + 5)(x + 1)}{(x - 2)(x + 1)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I stumbled upon following rational, where the right hand of equation is a simplification:

$$\frac{x^2 + 6x + 5}{x^2 - x - 2} = \frac{(x + 5)(x + 1)}{(x - 2)(x + 1)}$$

1. I can't understand how do you derive this simplification, what rules apply here?
2. Secondly, I want to search google for more (generic) information but I'm not even sure what should I search for?

**EDIT:**

Btw. this comes from [this](https://youtu.be/7Uos1ED3KHI) video link, but it doesn't explain my question.

Comment: Do you know how to factor quadratics? This is basically that.

Comment: No I don't, but thank you for the term, now I know what courses I need to watch!

Comment: Look for something like "how to factor quadratic", you should find lots of resources. Typical methods are completing the square and findings the roots I guess. There are some resources on this site as well, although they seem to be specific, maybe look at [Is there any method to factorize quadratic polynomial other than cross-method?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3374932) and [How to rearrange a quadratic into its factorized form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063274).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Find the roots of the numerator. These are $-5, -1$, Find the roots of the denominator. These are $2, -1$.

2) Search for "roots of quadratic equations" or "factoring quadratic polynomials".